# How to show Progress bar inside glide

Tags: android, imageview, android-glide

I want to show the circular progress bar inside the Glide when It is loading the images in the image view . But I am not able to do it.

**What I Have done so far**

I have declared the Progress bar in the xml in the following way

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    >
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/empty_clockwise"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@anim/loading_rotation"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:visibility="visible" />
        </FrameLayout>
```

and setting this in java in the following way

```
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                        .placeholder(progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable())
                        .listener(new RequestListener<Integer, GlideDrawable>() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onException(Exception e, Integer model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                return false;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, Integer model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                return false;
                            }
                        }).into(ivAnimationBoard);
            }
        });
```

But it is not showing inside the imageview but it is in the center of the activity.

**What i want :**

I want to show this progress bar inside the image view where Glide is being showing the image.

Answer (score 0):

Place the image inside the framelayout as well

```
<FrameLayout
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_centerInParent="true"
>

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
       />
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/empty_clockwise"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@anim/loading_rotation"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="visible" />


</Framelayout>
```

Comment: how this going to help ? I can Understand ?